# Graphviz node style : thicker contours?

Tags: graphviz

I'm looking for something pretty simple I believe: I would like my nodes to have thicker contours. For example this:

```
node [shape="box", color="red", style="filled", fillcolor="cyan"]
```

should give me cyan and box-shaped nodes, with red contour. What if I want thicker red lines? I thought maybe I should use width & height attributes, but I'm not sure how to.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`penwidth`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dpenwidth) :

> Specifies the width of the pen, in points, used to draw lines and
>   curves, including the boundaries of edges and clusters. The value is
>   inherited by subclusters. It has no effect on text.

Simply add for example `penwidth=5` to the attributes.